# What can be inferred according to the result of atomic operations?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, atomic

```cpp
// Thread 1:
obj.store(1,Release);  // #1

// Thread 2:
obj.store(2, Release);  // #2

//Thread 3:
 obj.load(Acquire);  // #3
 obj.load(Relaxed);  // #4
```

Assume `#3` reads the value `1` and `#4` reads the value `2`, it can easily infer that:

> 1. `#1` happens before `#3`, according to
>
> > [intro.races] p9.1
> >
> > > A synchronizes with B

> 2. `#2` does not happen before `#3`, according to
>
> > [intro.races] p18
> >
> > > If a side effect X on an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, then the evaluation B takes its value from X or from a side effect Y that follows X in the modification order of M.

> 3. `#3` happens before `#4`, according to
>
> > [intro.races] p10.1
> >
> > > A is sequenced before B

Conjunct the third condition and [intro.races] p16

> If a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, and A takes its value from a side effect X on M, then the value computed by B is either the value stored by X or the value stored by a side effect Y on M, where Y follows X in the modification order of M.

We may infer that the side effect at `#2` follows `#1` in the modification order of `obj`.

So, could we infer that `#1` happens before `#2` according to [intro.races] p15

> If an operation A that modifies an atomic object M happens before an operation B that modifies M, then A is earlier than B in the modification order of M.

It appears to me that "A is earlier than B in M" is only a necessary condition for "A happens before B", in other words, it seems we cannot infer that `#1` happens before `#2`, right?

Comment: In your first paragraph, "Assume #1 reads the value 1 and #2 reads the value 2,".  But #1 is a store.  Did you mean #3 reads `1` etc.?  Also, I'd recommend newlines or bullet list formatting for the quotes from the standard.  Note that with all these accesses being on the same object, no order stronger than `relaxed` matters.  The two stores are from different threads, and the two loads in the same thread on the same object already have to take the same or a later value in the modification order as the last load of the same object.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's a typo. I have edited my question. I wonder whether we can infer `A` happens before `B` if we know that `A` is earlier than `B` in the modification order according to [intro.races] p15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this sentence again:

> If an operation A that modifies an atomic object M happens before an operation B that modifies M, then A is earlier than B in the modification order of M.

This sentence takes the form "if X, then Y" where X is "operations A and B both modify an atomic object M, where A happens before B" and Y is "A is earlier than B in the modification order of M".

However, one cannot logically infer the converse, i.e. "if Y, then X". If A is earlier than B in the modification order of M, one cannot conclude from this rule alone that A happens before B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By this logic, I wonder what is the contrapositive of [intro.races] p14, if the original sentence takes the form "if X, then Y", I think it should be: if B does not happen before A, then the value computation of B is some unspecified A. The contrapositive of this proposition, IIUC, is that: If the value computation of B is not some unspecified A, then B **does does not happen before** A, right? "does not happen before" means happens after or unordered? So the negative of "does not happen before" means `A` happens before `B`?